# Which Android API to distribute app under

Tags: android, api

There are a few other threads that are similar, but I can't seem to find a difinitive answer, so I apologize if this seems a little repetetive.

Here's my situation.

My Android app compiles and runs under 1.5
I want to use supports-screen in my Manifest.
This means I have to compile with 1.6 in Eclipse or I get errors
I set the minSDK to 3 and the targetSDK to 4

Now, my question is, if I compile against 1.6 with the min/target sdk's as shown above, will the app show up in the Market Place for users of 1.5 phones AND will it run on 1.5 phones because of the minSDK setting even though I had to compile with 1.6?

Or, do I HAVE to compile with 1.5 for it to run on 1.5+ phones?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `<supports-screen>` you have to compile with 1.6 or greater. The app will show up for 1.5 devices when you set the minSdkVersion to 3.

I have an app that uses the following and I've seen comments from users of G1 say they have no problems running the app:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

Best explanation for this is on the [Android `uses-sdk` docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll give this a shot.  Worst case is I have to recompile under 1.5, release an update, and remove supports-screens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this approach will work for you ;) ... only caveat is that if you use relative layouts, be sure to test them on both 1.6 and 1.5 emulators. I've seen instances where the relative layouts behave differently on both.